# Internet Connection loop with WPF VB

Tags: wpf, vb.net, loops, iteration, internet-connection

Currently within my program I have it set up so that when the program is loaded it will check for a internet connection, if one is present then the program continues as normal but if there isn't a connection then a image is displayed. How would I go about adding a timer and loop with WPF VB to keep checking the application? The below code is a simple method I'm currently using, any feedback would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub CheckInternet()

    If My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable Then
        PicInternet.Visibility = True
    Else
        PicInternet.Visibility = False

    End If
End Sub
```

I'm also trying to rewrite a section from my previous code of standard to work on WPF vb which was previously used for a check internet program. The code below represents what I need converting from VB to WPF VB

```
If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf AccessPicture))
```

Comment: You can use [Network Location Awareness](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264321(v=vs.85).aspx) to be notified when connectivity changes.  WinRT has [managed wrappers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.aspx) for NLA that are easier to use.

Comment: Thanks for the response but could you give me some more advice on my question e.g. example?

Comment: You might want to check Network.IsAvailable - iirc it will return true for just about anything that looks like a working NIC, whether or not it can actually connect to something. You might be better trying to ping something.

Comment: Ok thanks but do you know how to rewrite If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf AccessPicture)) for wpf VB?